# Where is Devexpress cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, devexpress

Im using Asp.NET MVC + DevExpress. Im interested, where is devexpress cached files located when hosted in IIS-Express? I tried to investigate a little bit with ProccessMonitor, and found it loads too many files, they look like

```
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\DevExpress.f9faab5e#\ff9683433180259bc3c6cd3c0395af21\DevExpress.Dashboard.v14.1.Web.ni.dll
```

But i guess it's not cache
So how to find location of devexpress cache in IIS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching in IIS allows you to enable or disable page output caching, no matter you're using Devexpress or another files.
Devexpress files are stored inside the **bin** folder of your web site. Inside this folder you can store your custom themes for Devexpress controls.

If you want to create Cache rules or see current rules in IIS:

1. **Open IIS Manager**.

   - If you're using Windows Server 2012 o Server 2012 R2: on the taskbar, click Server Manager, click Tools and then IIS Manager.
   - If you're using Windows 8/8.1: press Windows key + X and then click Control Pnael. Click Administrative Tools and then double-clic IIS Manager.
   - If you're using Windows Server 2008 o Server 2008 R2: on the taskbar click Start, point to Administrative Tools and then click IIS Manager.
2. In the **Connections** pane, go to connection, site, application or directory for which you want to configure caching.
3. In the **Home** pane, go to **Output caching**.

If you want to change caching propteries (not the path for cached files) inside your application, you can modify your web.config file. Inside section  with the directive <**caching**> you can change:

- Enable / Disable cache.
- Enable / Disable kernel cache.
- Change cache size.
- Change response size.